# JavaScript RegEx to replace consecutive strings

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have a string that looks like this

`"+919357F%7F%7F%7F%00%00%00%29Your%20OTP%20for"`

I need all the consecutive `%7F` replaced with `~`

I found a nearly working solution with this command

```
"+919357F%7F%7F%7F%00%00%00%29Your%20OTP%20for".replace(/[%7F]{2,}/g, '~');
```

But for some reason it does eat away a couple of other `%` marks that I need to keep intact. Also I could not understand what the `{2,}` stands for? I know it is responsible for the consecutive replaces but not sure why 2 or 3 makes any difference?

Comment: What is expected output? Do you just want to extract the OPT?

Comment: That regex means, "replace any two or more consecutive sequences of ANY of these 3 characters: %, 7, F, with a single ~, repeatedly, until end of input". If the input was 5000 '7' characters followed by a single '%' then the result is a single ~.

Comment: Try this `"+919357F%7F%7F%7F%00%00%00%29Your%20OTP%20for".replace(/\%7F/g, '~');`

Comment: See [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). It explains your regex in english on the right, and you can quickly try stuff to learn, fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `[]` (*character class*) present in your RegEx with `()` (*capturing or non-capturing group*). Inside a character class, all the characters are treated as a separate pattern. So `[fo]` would match a single character either `f` or `o` and not group of characters like `fo`

```
str.replace(/(?:%7F){2,}/g, '~');
```

This would replace two or more `%7F` with `~`. That is, `%7F%7Fb%7F` would be changed to `~b%7F`

*Or*

```
str.replace(/(?:%7F)+/g, '~');
```

But this would replace one or more occurrences of `%7F` with `~`. So `%7F%7Fb%7F` would be changed to `~b~`

Comment: the second one suits my purpose.

Comment: i dont see any option to accept the answer. 
guide me pls.

Comment: @oshomaniac click the tick mark which exists below the down arrow (left side of my answer).

Comment: thanks - accepted the answer.

Have another similar query here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897876/regex-replace-pattern-control-characters-in-escaped-string

Would like help with the same.